# Phrase for (confirm it before you send email or letter)

Tags: grammar, phrases

I have a person who regularly makes mistakes in spelling or the data he writes are wrong, so I  want to tell someone that

(Please check and confirm the data or spellings before you send email or letter).

Is there any phrase for it?

Comment: Does 'review' look like a good option?

Comment: Context please? I don't understand what you're asking for. Confirm what?

Comment: @BraddSzonye Please see me updated Question.

Answer (score 4):

*Please **[proofread](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proofread)** your work before sending.*

According to M-W, *[proofread](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proofread)* means

> to read and correct mistakes in (a written or printed piece of writing)

Comment: proofread has more tendency to writing mistakes - as you mentioned. But, (s)he needs to point out two different types of contents (i.e., spelling mistakes and data accuracy) which are more than what proofread can refer to.

Comment: @Espanta I agree that proofreading is intended to find form mistakes. But content mistakes are also part of the process (as my endless *proofing* of old-style computer punch cards drummed into me). You could also add the term **fact-checking** (or **data-checking**) to the admonition if you wanted to be sure to cover all bases.

Comment: Thanks bib. I tend to agree with you and that's why I suggest to use accuracy and precision (IMHO, I think these words better fit data correctness). What do you think of my answer? Pls check.

Comment: I agree with proof or proofread. The act is wider than simple words unless the recipient is careless with strict word definitions. To ensure a clear message, I'd suggest, "Please ensure you have checked your data and proofread your document, including spellchecking, prior to sending it.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the person to double-check and proofread the text before sending. But if this is your employer or client you are talking about, a gentle 'You need to hire a PA with good copy-editing skills' would do.

Comment: +1 for ***double-check***. To me, *proofread* implies checking for *errors of **language***, but *double-checking* can also include making sure any ***facts and figures*** are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing, you may use the words accuracy, precision, cohesion, or completeness in whatever sentence you make. I suggest to formally write him/her, "Please ensure accuracy, precision, and cohesion of the contents before sending ...". In informal writing, your phrase would work or you may mix suggested words with your sentence. Better to use 'verify' instead of confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But is there any English phrase for it?

Comment: Not indeed as far as I know, because you are referring to two dissimilar types of contents (spelling errors and data accuracy), there would be hard to find a phrase for it, unless you coin it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you mention problems with data, I would say that they should *sanity check* their work:

> The act of checking that something does not contain elementary mistakes or impossibilities, or is not based on invalid assumptions

Source: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanity_check